# AWS Lambda getting timed out before completion of insert into table in RDS database

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, timeout, amazon-rds

Logic:
I have a AWS Lambda function which is performing insert operation into a table in RDS database. The lambda function is used to simply load a 'emp_details.csv' file data into a table 'emp_details' which is in RDS database. Works fine for 25,000 rows and 54 columns of data (file size 25MB) in 'emp_details.csv' file.

Problem:
Now the file 'emp_details.csv' has 500,000 rows and 40 columns of data (file size 400MB), AWS lambda is getting timed out after 15mins (max time out configuration) and data is not getting inserted in the 'emp_details' table as the insert operation has not completed yet.

How to handle this problem? I have already increased Memory size of AWS Lambda function also to 2GB.

Comment: The lambda maybe simply the wrong tool for the job. The next in line would be usually Fargate to use.

Comment: Are you inserting every row separately or are you inserting the data in batches? This can make a huge difference.

Comment: I am using AWS Lambda because I am triggering it when I load the csv file in s3 bucket. If I use Fargate then I might have to perform a scheduled task for this logic.

Comment: I am inserting data row by row.

Comment: If you can't speed up your upload, uploading batch data, the only solution can be use ECS also triggered by S3.
Check the documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/CloudWatch-Events-tutorial-ECS.html

Answer (score 1):

> AWS Lambda is not designed to support long running background
> processes. Ideal solution would be using ECS which can listen the
> event using SQS may be to process this.

However there is a bad solution as well if you don't want to go to ECS

1. When you receive the event take timestamp in a variable
2. Check if event is from SQS then start with specified rowId else go to step 3
3. Start processing in chunks may be 3k rows per chunk
4. After processing every chunk compare the time with initial timestamp if it is greater than 13 seconds, send an event to SQS with rowId and may be 5 delaySeconds and stop, else continue
5. Attach the SQS listener to same lambda
6. Stop